# How to save form radio value as a number in Firestore, instead of as a string?

Tags: forms, google-cloud-firestore, type-conversion

I'm building a form in Vue 3 and I'm trying to save the response value in Firestore as a number, instead of as a string.

`<input type="radio" id="something" v-model="rating" value="5">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's already built in Firestore:

1. go to the Firebase project via [Google Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. select Firestore database
3. select the collection
4. select a document
5. use cursor to highlight the field you wish to have as a number
6. click the "edit field" icon (pencil, second from the far right)
7. IMPORTANT: make note of the field's value before making changes
8. use the "type" drop-down and select "number"
9. enter the field's value, per step 7 above
10. click the blue "Update" button

*I just tested this and submitted my form again and the data type in that field was in fact a number instead of a string!*

If it's not yet built in Firestore, specify the field's data type as you create it. If you forget, just follow the steps above.